# Triple integral with multiple y boundaries.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

**Problem**: I am trying to calculate the mass for the solid bounded by $z = y^5 + 1, \ z = 0, \ y = x, \ y = x^2, \ y = 1.$ The density at each point is directly proportional to the square of the distance from the yz-plane.

I split the integral to simplify the calculation:

Assuming $\rho=kx^2$,

$k \cdot \int_{-1}^0 \int_{x^2}^1 \int_0^{y^5 + 1} x^2 dz \ dy \ dx + k \cdot \int_{0}^1 \int_x^{1} \int_0^{y^5 + 1} x^2 dz \ dy \ dx$

I am wondering if there is an easier way to set up the triple integral and if my limits of integration are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits of integration are perfectly correct, but there is an easier way to set up that integral. If you let $y$ go from $0$ to $1$ and $x$ go from $-\sqrt{y}$ to $y$, you can express it as a single integral:
$$k\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^y\int_0^{y^5+1}x^2\ dz\ dx\ dy$$
Both this and your formulation give the same answer $(\approx 0.298k)$, which I've shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rsymsvrrhl) along with a visual representation of the region of integration in the $xy$-plane.

**Edit:** The exact answer is given by$$k\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^yx^2\left(y^5+1\right)dx\ dy=\frac{k}3\int_0^1\left(y^8+y^{13/2}+y^3+y^{3/2}\right) dy=\frac{483}{1620}k$$